# ClassCast Exception being thrown

Tags: java, exception

```
    int [] arr =  {1,2,4,3,6,3,2,9};
    Collection<Integer> c = new HashSet<Integer>((Collection)Arrays.asList(arr));

    for(int x : c)
    {
        System.out.print(x);
    }
```

Above code is throwing classcast exception. Can anyone please help?

Comment: which line exactly throws the exception? upload your stack trace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` takes an array of *objects* (an `Object[]`). `int`s are not objects, which means it's impossible to interpret your `int[]` as an `Object[]` -- to do that, `arr` would have to be `Integer[]`. (Always remember that primitives and objects are fundamentally different, even if the compiler will sometimes conveniently convert between them for you.)

But `int[]` itself *is* an Object. That means `Arrays.asList(arr)` can use the varargs functionality to turn:

```
Arrays.asList(arr)
```

into:

```
Arrays.asList(new int[][] { arr })
```

This is a single-element array, whose only element is of type `int[]` -- an array of arrays.

In other words, the input to `Arrays.asList` is interpreted as a single object (the `int[] arr`), which is then wrapped into a one-element array of objects. So the result type is `List<int[]>`.

You then take this `List<int[]>` and try to cast it to a `Collection<Integer>`. This means that when you fetch the first item (which is an `int[]`), it's cast to an `Integer`. That's what's causing your ClassCastException.

Instead, you should use the varargs directly:

```
Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 3, 2, 9)
```

If you do that, the compiler has no choice but to treat each element as an object. It'll do that by auto-boxing each one into an `Integer`. The end result is something like this:

```
Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{ Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2), ... })
```

As a general piece of advice, the checked warnings are there for a reason. Until you become *very* comfortable with generics and erasures, I would recommend not suppressing them. The ClassCastException doesn't happen until you try to fetch something out of the `Collection<Integer>`, which could happen much later than when you put those elements in -- and possibly in another class altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), do use the diamond operator `<>` and don't try to add a primitive array to a `Collection` like that -

```
Integer[] arr = { 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 3, 2, 9 };
Collection<Integer> c = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr));

for (int x : c) {
    System.out.print(x);
}
```

The issue is that

```
int[] arr;
Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Returns a `List<int[]>`.