# Generics have unexpected behaior using primitives array instead of wrapper array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

The following code is returning a List of Integer:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[] {3,2,1};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Why is the same code using "int" returning a List of int[]:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {3,2,1};
List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
```

Comment: very-close-to-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814064/classcast-exception-being-thrown/26814101#26814101

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's treating that as a call using varargs and `int[]` as the type argument, i.e.

```
List<int[]> list = Arrays.<int[]>asList(new int[][] { arr });
```

The alternative would be to infer `T=int`... which is impossible, as Java generics don't support the use of primitive as type arguments. That restriction is the reason for the difference here.